# CONCAT Query displaying wrong Time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the following Query to add 2 hours to the date time from MYSQL database

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, '%Y-%m-%d '),
              DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(dt_tracker, INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%H:%m:%s'),
              DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, ' ')) AS dt_format, TYPE, event_desc, name, speed
FROM gs_user_events_data
```

For some reason the minutes is changed to 3 with all the times I have

This is the server time

**2021-03-11 04:44:18**

This is the output time

**2021-03-11 06:03:18**

The hours and seconds are correct but with all the times it makes the minutes **03**

Comment: Hint: What is [`%m`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and what month is it?

Comment: I now see the problem the 03 is same as the current month but how do I now overcome this issue, I have removed the %Y-%m-%d and the time still uses the month

Comment: I linked to the docs. Look through there for the placeholder you should be using.

Comment: @tadman you are a star Thank you so much

Comment: Worth adding a self-answer with your working solution if you got it on track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct function to this would be as follow

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, '%Y-%m-%d '),
              DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(dt_tracker, INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%H:%i:%s'),
              DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, ' ')) AS dt_format, TYPE, event_desc, name, speed
FROM gs_user_events_data
```

The wrong specifier was used as **%m** is used for Month and not Minutes